# Matplotlib how to make a continuous bar chart having different colours in different sections

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, bar-chart

Hi I want to make a bar chart that changes colours continuously without stacking it up. This is my current result [image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'B']
data2 = ['B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'B']
data3 = ['C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'B']

for i in range(len(data1) - 1):
    if data1[i] == "A":
        colour = "lightgrey"
        plt.bar('A', data1[i], color=colour, hatch='.')
    elif data1[i] == "B":
        colour = "grey"
        plt.bar('A', data1[i], color=colour, hatch='|')
    elif data1[i] == 'C':
        colour = "darkblue"
        plt.bar('A', data1[i], color=colour, hatch='+')
    elif data1[i] == 'D':
        colour = "pink"
        plt.bar('A', data1[i], color=colour, hatch='*')
    elif data1[i] == 'E':
        colour = "orange"
        plt.bar('A', data1[i], color=colour, hatch='x')

plt.show()
```

And I want to have something like this: [image]

Comment: "a bar chart that changes colours continuously without stacking it up" - do you mean an area chart?

Comment: @BigBen No, I mean a bar chart. I want a bar to change every single time it is going to see a certain value as it is shown above

Comment: In matplotlib, there is a method called bar. This allows you to make bar charts inside matplotlib. Unfortunately, this is as far as my knowledge goes. There is a link to help you make bar charts. https://datatofish.com/bar-chart-python-matplotlib/#:~:text=%20Steps%20to%20Create%20a%20Bar%20Chart%20in,For%20this%20step%2C%20capture%20the%20above...%20More%20

Comment: It might be me but I just see a stacked bar chart. What is different in your desired output?

Comment: @Mr.T When I am stacking up the bar chart it sorts the value from a to e and I dont want that. I want my bar to change the colour whenever it is going to see or check a certain value

Comment: Okay, I am officially incapable to understand the difference to a stacked bar chart. But you got your answer, and that is what matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bars are overlapped. Let's try to plot them again with `bottom`:

```
colors = {'A':'lightgrey','B':'grey',
         'C':'darkblue', 'D':'pink',
         'E':'orange'}
hatches = {'A':'.','B':'|','C':'+','D':'*', 'E':'x'}

for i, val in enumerate(data1):
    plt.bar('A', 0.9,, 
            bottom=i, 
            color=colors[val],
            hatch=hatches[val])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have a single "A" as a label?

Comment: @JanKlimaszewski that was a mistake from my end. The updated code produces one `A` only.